# Ammo.js setRotation not matching getRotation

Tags: javascript, ammo.js

I'm using the Ammo.js physics library (https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/)

Here's an example of the problem:

```js
const a = [-0.0000064798259700182825, -0.0013201627880334854, 0.0000027575993044592906, 0.9999991059303284]
const t = new Ammo.btTransform();
t.setIdentity();
const q = new Ammo.btQuaternion(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
t.setRotation(q)
const r = t.getRotation()
assert(a[0] === r.x()) // fails here as r.x() === -0.000006479827334260335
assert(a[1] === r.y())
assert(a[2] === r.z())
assert(a[3] === r.w())
```

I was expecting to get the same values for the rotation as I had set, but didn't get them. I've also tried normalizing the quaternion first, but that was not the problem.
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with the library, but rather a limitation of JavaScript. To achieve arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic in JavaScript, you should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251971/6456163). Unfortunately it is unlikely that any of those libraries will be compatible with `ammo.js`, so I'm not going to bother including those code samples in this answer.

For your specific library, [this issue](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/issues/299#issuecomment-622572546) explains how to use double precision instead of float precision. As the thread explains, you will need to modify the `btScalar.h` file to turn on `BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION`. The author also mentions possibly needing a modification to the `ammo.idl` file, but does not go into further detail.

For further support I recommend either reaching out to the author on that issue (which closed in 2020) or creating your own issue requesting more detail on how to make the necessary changes.